# Can't seem to change length of string[]

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array in C#:

```
string[] foo = new string[11];
```

The length of foo array has been 10, I only changed it to 11 because I needed an extra value. My only problem is: I can't seem to change the length of the array. If I change it to 11, like in the above example, set a break point and debug, after the compiler passes this line, it still has a length of 10.

Now when I add a watch `foo = new string[11]` after the compiler passes this line, all the values are erased and the length is changed to 11. Basically I have no idea what is going on, especially why adding a watch has an effect on the runtime values of variables.

Does anybody have any idea what is happening here?

```
    public string[] getValues()
    {
        //Why does this only have 10 dimensions after initialization?????
        string[] values = new string[11];

        string[] temp = ddlProjectnumber.Text.Split('-'); //<----- here I set break point.
        values[0] = temp[0].Trim();
        values[1] = tbTask.Text;
        values[2] = ddlSubstitute.Text;
        values[3] = ddlCategory.Text;
        values[4] = ddlSubcategory.Text;
        values[5] = cbFinished.Checked.ToString();

        if (propertychanged)
        {
            values[6] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        values[7] = cbJourney.Checked.ToString();

        return values;
    }
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. I don't think you're actually debugging against your latest code.

Comment: I already did that multiple times. I even restarted my Dev-VM, all to no avail.

Comment: Try values[10] = "xyz"; what will happen?

Comment: new string[11] creates an array with 11 strings, indexed from 0 to 10. Do you need a values[11]? then you need 12 strings!

Comment: Regarding that watch value changing things, any expression in the condition has to be evaluated, and an assignment operator does change state.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly but I can change 11 to whatever I like, it always compiles with a length of 10. Like it is stuck with some old code as Dan said.

Comment: @Sean: ok I didn't know that until now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Arrays are fixed-sized, use a `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will be easier to maintain if you create a class to hold your values:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
    public string Substitute { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Subcategory { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PropChangedDate { get; set; }
    public bool Journey { get; set; }
}
```

Then adjust your method to just populate an instance of the class and return that instead:

```
public MyClass GetValues()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass
    {
        ProjectNumber = ddlProjectnumber.Text.Split('-').First().Trim(),
        Task = tbTask.Text,
        Substitute = ddlSubstitute.Text,
        Category = ddlCategory.Text,
        Subcategory = ddlSubcategory.Text,
        Finished = cbFinished.Checked,
        Journey = cbJourney.Checked
    };

    if (propertychanged)
        myClass.PropChangedDate = DateTime.Now;

    return myClass;
}
```

Now you don't have to guess which values were stored in each element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

okay I played around a bit and after changing my configuration from debug to release and then to debug again, it apparently fixed itself. I guess it really was old code, but for some reason, it did not recompile correctly after I cleaned and rebuild my solution. anyway it works now :)

Comment: Although you have a working solution now, I highly recommend the solution by @GrantWinney.